# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'slideNext') (Ionic 5)

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I created an app in Ionic 5 with multiple pages in which slides are used. I created a service in order to store all the global functions and I call them from any TS file of every page.

When I tried to call the fucntions (which are in service) in pages everything is OK except for the fucntions which contains references to slides (ionic slides).

Could you please help me if you have any idea ? don't hesitate if you want more details about the issue.

Thanks in advance

service.ts file

```
import { Injectable, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams, IonSlides } from '@ionic/angular';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class HttpService {



  @ViewChild('slides') 
  slides:IonSlides;

  slideOptions = {
    initialSlide: 0,
    slidesPerView: 1,
    autoplay: false,
    pagination : {
      el: '.swiper-pagination',
      clickable: true
    },
    //allowSlidePrev:true,
    /*
    coverflowEffect: {
      rotate: 50,
      stretch: 0,
      depth: 100,
      modifier: 1,
    },*/
      slideShadows: true,
  };

  constructor(private router: Router){}

  
  async navigate(){
    this.router.navigate(['tabs/tab2'])
    await this.waitBefore(10);// Sleep thread for 10ms seconds (permet de réinitialiser radio states)
    this.router.navigate(['/quiz-maison'])
  }


  isOK:boolean=null;
  answers: any;
  hasAnswered: boolean = false;
  initState: boolean = false;
  score: number = 0;
  //allowSlidePrev=false;
  showAnswer(event:any) {
    // get data throught event emitter
      this.answers = event.target.value;
      if (this.answers=="correct"){
      //this.answers= this.bon;
      this.isOK=true;
      this.score++;

      }

      else{
      //this.answers= this.mauv;
      this.isOK=false;false
      }
      this.hasAnswered = true;
  console.log("I'm showAnswer fct");
  console.log(this.slides);
  this.slides.slideNext();
  }

  ionSlideChange(){
  this.answers =null;
  this.isOK=null;
  this.hasAnswered = false;
  }

  
waitBefore(ms: number)
{
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

  async goNextSlide(){
    await this.waitBefore(1000);// Sleep thread for 3 seconds
    //this.slides.lockSwipeToPrev(false);
    this.slides.slideNext();
    this.slides.lockSwipeToPrev(true);
    console.log("I'm goNextSlide fct");
  }

}
```

maison.ts file:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { IonSlides, NavController, NavParams } from '@ionic/angular';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { HttpService } from '../../service/http.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-quiz-maison',
  templateUrl: './quiz-maison.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./quiz-maison.page.scss'],
  //providers: [NavParams]
})
export class QuizMaisonPage implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild('slides') slides: IonSlides;
    slideOptions = {
    initialSlide: 0,
    slidesPerView: 1,
    autoplay: false,
    pagination : {
      el: '.swiper-pagination',
      clickable: true
    },
    //allowSlidePrev:true,
    /*
    coverflowEffect: {
      rotate: 50,
      stretch: 0,
      depth: 100,
      modifier: 1,
    },*/
      slideShadows: true,
  };
  
  constructor(private http:HttpService){}

  ngOnInit() {
  }


  showAnswer(){
  this.http.showAnswer(event)
  }

  goNextSlide(){
    this.http.goNextSlide();
    }

    goToAnswers(){
      this.http.goToAnswers();
    }

  ionSlideChange(){
    this.http.ionSlideChange()

  }

  waitBefore(){
    let ms: number;
    this.http.waitBefore(ms)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

make sure you have <ion-slides #slides> on your html file since thats the name you gave the variable in your maison.ts

```
  <ion-slides pager="true" style="height: 100%;" #questionario (ionSlideWillChange)="slideChanged()">
```

```
 @ViewChild('questionario') slides: IonSlides;
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I did that (create a reference for slides by adding #slides in the HTML) but the issue still here

Answer (score 0):

Try passing a reference to your service class (make show answers also take the slides as an input parameter) , also, I think it is not normal to have a @ViewChild inside of your service.

Per the angular docs `Property decorator that configures a view query. The change detector looks for the first element or the directive matching the selector in the view DOM. If the view DOM changes, and a new child matches the selector, the property is updated.`

The service, by its very nature, is not tied to any view. Thus that is why it is undefined since it has no view that it is attached to.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and the details. But I'm wondring, why when I call other function like CONSOLE.LOG (defined in service) and called in page the call works fine !! Why it's different for the slide component (IonSlides). I have to mention that I imported import { HttpService } from './service/http.service'; in app.module.ts and added it provides list like this:  providers: [{ provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy },AppVersion, HttpService]

Comment: I you ask the question why I diden't added it in IMPORT list of app.module.ts, it was the first idea for me but I got the error : "Does Not Have emod"

Comment: So is it the service itself that is null?

Comment: Honestly I don't know, I'm blocked and the only way I found to go ahead is to create the same function in every TS file of my app pages. I know it's not a good practice.